# Trouble replicating demo with my own data. .vtk [

Tags: xtk

I am trying to replicate [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/toolkit/edge/xtk/lessons/tree/master/09/#run) with my own data.

```
window.onload = function() {

// create and initialize a 3D renderer
var r = new X.renderer3D();
r.init();

// create a mesh and associate it to the VTK Point Data
var p = new X.mesh();
p.file = 'http://x.babymri.org/?pits.vtk';
```

I understand you cannot simply point to the local `.vtk` file. I have read that `webgl` required the file to be served, so I am now correctly serving it from `localhost`.

I have placed exactly the same data (as served to the above example) locally and saved it in the file `DATA.vtk`.

I have modified `MIME` types inside IIS manager so that `.vtk` is `text/html` and when you point to either the raw data's url (in the original example) or my `localhost` data, they look exactly the same.

However, it still does not work. Specifically, this is my error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null xtk.js:179
```

Here is a picture of what I'm talking about...

[image]

Comment: Currently, only ASCII .vtk is supported. Maybe you are reading a binary .vtk file? You can use f.e. 3D Slicer to convert it to ASCII.

Comment: my file i believe is ASCII as it includes # vtk DataFile Version 2.0 Really cool data ASCII DATASET POLYDATA POINTS 137781 float -6.02304 -84.4786 -7.80054...       do i need to save the .vtk with different encoding or something?

Comment: I just tested putting all the data into notepad and saving as DATA.vtk and make sure to flag it to save in the ASCI format...  still same error.